# Pythonic way to send contents of a file to a pipe and count # lines in a single step

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, bigdata

given the > 4gb file myfile.gz, I need to zcat it into a pipe for consumption by Teradata's fastload. I also need to count the number of lines in the file. Ideally, I only want to make a single pass through the file. I use awk to output the entire line ($0) to stdout and through using awk's END clause, writes the number of rows (awk's NR variable) to another file descriptor (outfile).

I've managed to do this using awk but I'd like to know if a more pythonic way exists.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os import path

the_file = "/path/to/file/myfile.gz"

outfile = "/tmp/%s.count" % path.basename(the_file)
cmd = ["-c",'zcat %s | awk \'{print $0} END {print NR > "%s"} \' ' % (the_file, outfile)]
zcat_proc = Popen(cmd, stdout = PIPE, shell=True)
```

The pipe is later consumed by a call to teradata's fastload, which reads from

```
"/dev/fd/" + str(zcat_proc.stdout.fileno())
```

This works but I'd like to know if its possible to skip awk and take better advantage of python. I'm also open to other methods. I have multiple large files that I need to process in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting lines and unzipping `gzip`-compressed files can be easily done with Python and its standard library.  You can do everything in a single pass:

```
import gzip, subprocess, os
fifo_path = "path/to/fastload-fifo"
os.mkfifo(fifo_path)
fastload_fifo = open(fifo_path)
fastload = subprocess.Popen(["fastload", "--read-from", fifo_path],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
with gzip.open("/path/to/file/myfile.gz") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
         fastload_fifo.write(line)
    print "Number of lines", i + 1
os.unlink(fifo_path)
```

I don't know how to invoke Fastload -- subsitute the correct parameters in the invocation.

Comment: This nearly works as-is but one of the drawbacks of our implementation of fastload is that the fastload control file itself must be stdin. Therefore, the gunzip'd data needs to come from a different source. Is there a way to open up a named pipe in python without having to invoke a shell command?

Comment: @NeilKodner: Then probably the easiest way is to use [`os.mkfifo()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) to create a named pipe.  I'll update my answer...

Comment: `enumerate(f, 1)` will make the line count start at 1 not 0

Answer (score 7):

There's no need for either of `zcat` or Awk. Counting the lines in a gzipped file can be done with

```
import gzip

nlines = sum(1 for ln in gzip.open("/path/to/file/myfile.gz"))
```

If you want to do something else with the lines, such as pass them to a different process, do

```
nlines = 0
for ln in gzip.open("/path/to/file/myfile.gz"):
    nlines += 1
    # pass the line to the other process
```

Comment: and gzip.open() intelligently iterates through the file, yielding each line, rather than loading its contents into RAM?

Comment: @NeilKodner: yes, `gzip.open` will uncompress parts of the file on demand, like `zcat`.

Comment: Would I still use subprocess.Popen to create the pipe that Fastload reads from or should I go about a different method? I need to write the gunzip'd data to /dev/fd/n. In the past, the awk command was writing to stdout=PIPE and awk/zcat was the actual command. in this case, i won't have a shell command because i'm using python to iterate through the gzip'd file.

Comment: using the first solution, if `/path/to/file/myfile.gz` would be a file of a million of lines, would you be creating a list with a million of `1`s?

Comment: @Neil: If Fasload can read from stdin (it should be able to -- if in doubt, just pass `/dev/sdin` as input filename), see the solution in my answer.  It is basically the same as this answer, but also deals with the part of getting the data to Fastload.  (And it ensures that the input file will be closed, though this is a minor difference.)

Comment: i mistakenly added a line to @larsmans answer instead of my original post. hopefully this will be edited.

Comment: @SvenMarnach stdin won't necessarily work because the fastload command itself reads something else from stdin - namely its control file. We need to gunzip, on the fly, to a pipe and then we generate a TD Fastload control with the location of the pipe. We then invoke fastload using fastload < control_file.ctl. The control_file.ctl has a reference to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one simple line of bash:

```
zcat myfile.gz | tee >(wc -l >&2) | fastload
```

This will print the line count on stderr. If you want it somewhere else you can redirect the wc output however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should not be possible to pipe the data to Fastload at all, so it would be great if somebody post here an exact example if he could.

From Teradata documentation on the Fastload configuration http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2411_071A/2411Ch03.026.028.html#ww1938556

FILE=filename
Keyword phrase specifying the name of the data source that contains the input data. fileid must refer to a regular file. **Specifically, pipes are not supported**.